# ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized

Tags: android, arraylist

I have this Method():

```
  private List<? extends Map<String, String>> creaListaDeGrupos() {

      ArrayList resultado_padre = new ArrayList();
      for (int i = 0; i < listadoPartidas.getPartidas().size(); i++) {
          HashMap<String, String> padre = new HashMap<String, String>();
          padre.put("posicionLista", posicionlista.get(i));
          padre.put("codigo", codigoBaremo.get(i));
          padre.put("descripcionBaremo", descripcionBaremoPadre.get(i));
          padre.put("cantidad", cantidad.get(i));
          padre.put("importe", importe.get(i));
          padre.put("estado", estado.get(i));
          padre.put("observaciones", observaciones.get(i));
                    resultado_padre.add(padre);
      }
return resultado_padre
}
```

And Lint return me the error:

> ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList should be parameterized

But i cant do

```
ArrayList<String> resultado_padre = new ArrayList();
```

Because this isnt a arraylist of strings, what type bust will be?

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating the same type you are returning:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

There is no need to declare the implementation type, i.e. `ArrayList`. The `List` interface is more general, so when declaring variables as a concrete type, ask yourself if this is necessary. See 
[Programming against interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Likewise in the spirit of DRY you don't need to duplicate the specific generics on the right side of the equals: List<HashMap<String, String>> = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

```
 private List<Map<String, String>> creaListaDeGrupos() { 

            List<Map<String, String>> resultado_padre = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>() ; 
            for (int i = 0; i < listadoPartidas.getPartidas().size(); i++) { 
                Map<String, String> padre = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                padre.put("posicionLista", posicionlista.get(i)); 
                padre.put("codigo", codigoBaremo.get(i)); 
                padre.put("descripcionBaremo", descripcionBaremoPadre.get(i)); 
                padre.put("cantidad", cantidad.get(i)); 
                padre.put("importe", importe.get(i)); 
                padre.put("estado", estado.get(i)); 
                padre.put("observaciones", observaciones.get(i)); 
                resultado_padre.add(padre); 
            } 
return resultado_padre 
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Map<String,String>> to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>

Answer (score 0):

It will be `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`