# Warning ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, list, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045788/arraylist-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-arrayliste-should-be-param)

In order to save an ArrayList with payments done by one member I want to change the List of Payment ID's into a string, so I created the following method:

```
public String fromArraytoString(ArrayList items){
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(items));
        return json.toString();
           }
```

But I get the following warning:

```
   ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**You definitely should read this tutorial on Java generics**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

**In a nutshell:**

Many Java classes and types (called *generic classes* or *generic types*), typically collections, have so called *type parameters*, such as `E` in `ArrayList<E>` (`E` is just an arbitrary chosen name, other classes name it as `T` or whatever):

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends ... {

    public E get(int index) { ... }

    public boolean add(E element) { ... }

    // other methods...
}
```

Now, when you create an instance of such class, you define a concrete value of the type parameter, for example `String` (`E` can usually be evaluated to whatever type you want):

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

From now on, all the `E`s are "replaced" by `String` for the `stringList` variable, so you can add only Strings to it and get only Strings from it. The compiler checks for you that you don't mistakenly add an object of another type:

```
stringList.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
// compile error - cannot add Integer to ArrayList of Strings
```

---

However, because generics were added to Java 5, it is still possible to write code without them for backwards compatibility. So you can write:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

But you lose all the type checking benefits. `E`s in method signatures become simply `Object`s.

```
list.add(Integer.valueOf(42)); // adding an Integer
list.add("aaa"); // adding a String

Object something = list.get(0); // unknown type of returned object, need to cast
Integer i0 = (Integer) something; // this unsafe cast works...
Integer i1 = (Integer) list.get(1); // but this fails with a ClassCastException
// because you cannot cast a String to Integer
```

The fact that using a *raw type* (that is a generic type with its type parameters omitted) is unsafe, is the reason for the warning you've got. Instead of just `ArrayList`, use `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>` or whatever the type of your `items` is.

Comment: Wow thanks to this! Very clear explanation @Natix. +1

Comment: Can you give the exact solution for the question asked?

Answer (score 5):

What kind of objects are stored in the ArrayList? You need to add it to the declaration. It's always

```
ArrayList<Type>
```

So if it's a list of JSONObjects, you would put

```
ArrayList<JSONObject>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Java compiler tries to do certain checking for you. The way you have written it you effectively tell compiler you will receive ArrayList of Object's as parameter.
It's simply encouraging you to specify class of objects you will to store in ArrayList. Specifying `ArrayList<MyClass>` or `ArrayList <?>` would get rid of the warning. Second version effectively tells compiler that you would pass ArrayList of objects of class not known at compile time.

I think it might be useful for you to read a bit about generics in Java.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 1):

`JsonArray`'s constructor expects to receive a generic type `Collection` with parameter `T`,  while `items`'s type is `ArrayList` without type specified(i.e raw type). You may check this question to get some idea about raw type: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Solution 1(recommended): pass `items` with paramter `T` or specify concrete type such as `String`. This question might help you in your specific problem: [convert ArrayList<MyCustomClass> to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylist-to-jsonarray).

Solution 2: add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the method `fromArraytoString`.
This is not recommended, but you can refer to this question: [What is SuppressWarnings ("unchecked") in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I have a list of ID's (let's say, 1, 2, 3...) that are all payments in a database. I just want to store this list of ID's in an ArrayList in a database. Can you give me a small example?

Comment: Just changing `fromArraytoString(ArrayList items)` in  to `fromArraytoString(ArrayList<String> items)` might work(If your items are all of `String` type.