# How to solve warning when using liferay-ui:search-container in JSP?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing a portlet in Liferay 6.1 using `Liferay MVC famework`. When I use

```
<liferay-ui:search-container />
```

Eclipse allways shows me the following warning message

> SearchContainer is a raw type. References to generic type
>   `SearhcContainer<R>` should be parameterized

**JSP code fragment:**

```
<%
    List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.search(...);
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= users %>"
        total="<%= users.size() %>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row 
            className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
            keyProperty="userId"
            modelVar="userVar">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="name"
                value="<%= userVar.getFullName() %>" />

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

I have searched many examples. I've imported them into my workspace. And they also show me the same Warning message when `search-container` tag is used.

An example is this portlet: [Event listing portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-docs/tree/master/devGuide/code/devGuide-sdk/portlets/event-listing-portlet) 
in [/docroot/html/eventlisting/view.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-docs/blob/master/devGuide/code/devGuide-sdk/portlets/event-listing-portlet/docroot/html/eventlisting/view.jsp) Eclipse shows me the same warning.

I've not found any solution searching nor in google neither in stackoverflow. I have found many references to warnings in jsp, but no when the warning occurs when using some tag.

If it's possible, I don't want to disable JSP Validation or use some `@SuppressWarnings`.

I would really like to know if there is a correct way to avoid this warning in JSP when I use this taglib.

I'm working with 
- Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2 
- Eclipse Luna Release 4.4.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class SearchContainer is a *generic class* (http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/SearchContainer.html), and as all generic class produce that warning when you try to instantiate without pass a type argument.

For more details:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html
- [Warning ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207005/why-warning-arraylist-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-arrayliste-sh)

But SearchContainer is instantiated via tablib, so i think eclipse "see through" the taglib and produce the warning. The problem probably will be in that generated code and  I really guess that this problem has no a pratical solution (hook/ext the taglib code? really?)

Sorry for this (un)answer !

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guessed there was a way, unknown to me, to pass the type argument when instantiating via taglib. I'll give some time before accepting your answer. May be someone comes up with another answer or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your total attribute in liferay-ui-search-container tag. Instead of using in search-container-result.

```
    List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.search(...);
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container total="<%= users.size() %>">

    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= users %>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row 
            className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
            keyProperty="userId"
            modelVar="userVar">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="name"
                value="<%= userVar.getFullName() %>" />

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
 

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```