# Get value from a raw ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a ArrayList that's not specified as double/float but it contains double float values as `22.33`, `12.56`, `34`, `21`...

I actually have two that I use when I read from a file to savee the data to.
They look like this

```
static List<MySample> data = new ArrayList<MySample>();
static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

With `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList();` I can use a simple
loop like:

```
double sum = 0;
double count = 0;
for (Double a : list) {
    sum += a; 
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Average is   " + sum / count);
```

But when I use:

```
for (Object o : list) {
    // How can I do the same with some code here?
}
```

How can I do the same with the `Object` loop?
I hope you did understand my problem.

Ok, here is my method where I unserialize a file and where I want to get the values from...

```
public void deserialize(List<MySample>listan, String path) {
   double sum=0;
   int count=0;
try {File file = new File(path);ObjectInputStream in = new 
   ObjectInputStream(newFileInputStream(file));             
   listan = (ArrayList<MySample>) in.readObject();


        for(Object obj: listan){

            //here I need the code
}
         System.out.println("Good work!");
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Either enforce the List to accept <Double> or cast it.

Comment: Why `list` is a raw-type?

Comment: Preferred way is to be specific about the list type as `Double` or `Float`

Comment: You should always use _generic_ collections. See this answer for a quick intro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207005/why-warning-arraylist-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-arrayliste-sh/14207100#14207100

Comment: You should, at the very least, use: `static List<Number> list` since `Double` and `Float` extend `Number`.

Comment: One more reason to [use a generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). TL;DR: the only reason it is possible to use raw types is backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all of the above but it did not work, but I figured it out.

My method looks like this

```
public void deserialize(List <MySample>listan, String path) {
   double sum=0;
   int count=0;
   double average=0;
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new   
        FileInputStream(file));
        listan = (ArrayList<MySample>) in.readObject();

        for (Object o:listan){

            sum += Double.parseDouble((String) o);
            count ++;
            average = sum/count;

}

         System.out.printf("The average on %s är %.2f ", item, average);

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

It struck me that Java has many types of code that does the same thing.
Why just not have one general line of code for this?
There is example differents codes that does the same thing but did not work with 
my methods...example

```
sum += a.doubleValue();
sum += (double) o;
sum += ((Double)o).doubleValue();
```

Theese did not work but this code did the work for me

```
 sum += Double.parseDouble((String) o);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ensure `list` contains all double values, cast it to `Double` (in order not to break the whole loop, have to put `try/catch` in the loop... It maybe not high performance):

```
for (Object o : list) {
    try {
        sum += ((Double)o).doubleValue();
        count++;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
    }
}
```

But suggest not to use raw type list like `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();`, the better way is `List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();`.

Comment: And what to add/do if it is not a Double? ;)

Comment: @dbf If the `list` cannot ensure all elements are double, I have to add `try/catch` within the loop, because if one element cannot be cast to double, it should not break the whole loop. Only when no exception happens the count should increase one.

Answer (score 1):

While the following will work for you:

```
        Double sum = (double) 0;
        int count =0;
        for (Object o: list){
            sum= sum+ (Double)o;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Average is   " + sum / count);
```

What you should do is use [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) which provide compile-time type safety.

```
        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list.add(22.33);
        list.add(12.56);
        list.add(34.21);

        Double sum = (double) 0;
        int count =0;
        for (Double o: list){
            sum= sum+ o;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Average is   " + sum / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast:

```
for (Object o:list){
    sum += (double) o;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: that gives me this error    java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Comment: @TapaniYrjölä That is why you shouldn't use raw types. You have a `String` in your list that was supposed to only contain `Double`.

Comment: Yes, this is better: ((Double) o).doubleValue()

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the object a Double, at least if you're sure the objects are of type `Double`. It's basically the old way of doing things, from before Java 5.

```
for (Object o:list){
     total += ((Double)o).doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should, at the very least, use: `static List<Number> list` since `Double` and `Float` extend `Number`.

Then for your sum, you can get the double value. This is the proper use of generics.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumberList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();

        list.add(1.4142135623730950);
        list.add(2.71828f);
        list.add(3.14159265359d);

        // Average is: 2.4246954309812287
        System.out.println("Average is: " + avg(list));
    }

    public static double avg(List<Number> list) {
        double sum = 0;
        double count = 0;

        for (Number a : list) {
            sum += a.doubleValue();
            count++;
        }

        return sum / count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you do not need to keep track of a count, unless you are skipping values in the list. Simply use `list.size()` as the denominator in the return statement.